# Randomly generating answer after selecting two buttons

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am attempting to create a program to suggest a restaurant after the user clicks on two buttons(options on dining and food type). I was able to create this in python via input, but i'm not sure how to translate it to javascript.

I have the HTML portion create for the options that I would like to give the user. However, since I'm not sure how to take the answers and grab a suggestion I haven't created any arrays to randomly grab from.

This is what I was able to do in Python

---

```
import random

#Questions asked of User

dinner = input("Are you in the mood for fries, rice, bread or pasta? ").lower()

dining = input("What kind of dining experience you like? Dine-In, Take Out, Delivery, Drive-Thru? ").lower()

#Food options
fries = ['Clark Burger','Sunnys','Mission BBQ','Popeyes','Chick Fil A','All About Burger','The Local Fry']
fries_drive = ['Popeyes','Chick Fil A','Mcdonalds','Wendys','Burger King']
fries_delivery = ['Chinese','Stokos','The Spot']

bread = ['Get a Sub','Make a sandwich','Order some Pizza','Get a Lobster Roll','Go to Ekiben']
bread_delivery = ['Pizza','Stokos']

pasta = ['Go to Olive Garden','Go to Noodles & Company','Get a Pizza','Make some spaghetti']
pasta_delivery = ['Dominos','Stokos']

rice = ['Go to Asian Taste','Japanese or Sushi','Go to Brown Rice','Get Korean BBQ','Go to Chipotle','Go to Ekiben']
rice_delivery = ['Chinese']



#Food Options if user wants take out

if (dinner == "fries") and (dining == "take out" or dining == "dine in"):
print(random.choice(fries))
elif dinner == "fries" and dining == "drive thru" :
print(random.choice(fries_drive))
elif dinner == "fries" and dining == "delivery" :
print(random.choice(fries_delivery))

elif (dinner == "rice") and (dining == "take out" or dining == "dine in") :
print(random.choice(rice))
elif dinner == "rice" and dining == "delivery" :
print(random.choice(rice_delivery))

elif (dinner == "bread") and (dining == "take out" or dining == "dine in") :
print(random.choice(bread))
elif dinner == "bread" and dining == "delivery" :
print(random.choice(bread_delivery))

elif (dinner == "pasta") and (dining == "take out" or dining == "dine in"):
print(random.choice(pasta))
elif dinner == "pasta" and dining == "delivery" :
print(random.choice(pasta_delivery))

else :
print("Choose from one of the choices given. Or else you won't get anything!")
```

---

And this is the HTML Im attempting to manipulate with Javascript.

```
<!-- Food options -->

  <div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="images/fries.png" alt="Fries">
    <button type="button1" class="btn btn-outline-primary button1">Fries</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="images/rice.png" alt="Rice">
    <button type="button2" class="btn btn-outline-primary button2">Rice</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="images/pasta.png" alt="Pasta">
    <button type="button3" class="btn btn-outline-primary button3">Pasta</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="images/bread.png" alt="Bread">
    <button type="button4" class="btn btn-outline-primary button4">Bread</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<!-- dining options -->

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="images/dine-in.png" alt="Dine-in">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info button5">Dine-In</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="images/take-out.png" alt="Take-Out">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info button6">Take-Out</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="images/Delivery.png" alt="Delivery">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info button7">Delivery</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="images/Drive-Thru.png" alt="Drive-Thru">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info button8">Drive-Thru</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using templates. In Flask, you can store variables and use them in HTML. For instance in your html file,

```
   {% for ele in similar_list %}
  <tr>  
    <td style="border: 1px solid white">{{ ele[0] }} </td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid white">{{ ele[1] }} </td>
  </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

And then in your app.py file, you could do this

```
@app.route('/result',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def result():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        arr_2d = "SOME code here"
        return render_template('calc.html', similar_list=arr_2d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use `prompt` instead `input` like Python.